# how to use 'this' in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

this is my HTML code :

```
<div id="staticlinks">
<a class="thumb" href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png"/></a>
<a class="thumb" href="https://www.twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png" /></a>
<a class="thumb" href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/youtube.png" /></a>
<a class="thumb" href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/feed.png" /></a>
<a class="thumb" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/google.png" /></a>

</div>
```

and this is jQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
  $('.thumb').hover(
    function(){
      $(".thumb img", this).animate({height: '80px' , width:'80px'}, 'slow');
    }, function(){
      $(".thumb img", this).animate({height: '60px', width: '60px'}, 'slow');
    }
  );
}
);
```

the problem is when I remove 'this' from `$(".thumb img", this)` then all the images gets animated. And if I put it here then the animation doesn't take place. I am not getting the problem.

Comment: This refer to `$('.thumb')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $('.thumb').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){
      var size = e.type=='mouseenter' ? 80 : 60 ;
      $("img", this).animate({height: size , width: size }, 800);
  });
});
```

Your handler was already pointed to `.thumb` which are the `<a>` elements, than you were again pointing to ANY `".thumb img", this` where `this` was not relevant any more.
Now, by doing `"img", this` you're actually saying `"img", children of THIS hovered` which will work as expectd.

Above it's a nice way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

`$(".thumb img", this)` means "find all `.thumb` elements within `this`, then find all their descendant `img` elements". You just want to find all the `img` elements within `this`, since `this` **is** the `.thumb` element.

All you need to do is `$('img', this)`.

Note that it is rather more intuitive (and *minutely* faster!) to use `find` instead.

```
$(this).find('img')
```

This means exactly the same thing but, I think, is a little easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
  $('.thumb').hover(
    function(){
      $(this).animate({height: '80px' , width:'80px'}, 'slow');
    }, function(){
      $(this).animate({height: '60px', width: '60px'}, 'slow');
    }
  );
}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("img", this);` instead of `$(".thumb img", this)` It will take every `img` under `this`, which is the hovered `.thumb`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("img", this)
```

You are hovering the `.thumb` so you should do it like this.

or this way:

```
$(this).find('img').animate({....})
```

Answer (score 1):

**What is “this”?**

> In many object-oriented programming languages, this (or self) is a
>   keyword which can be used in instance methods to refer to the object
>   on which the currently executing method has been invoked.

(from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_%28computer_programming%29))

In jQuery, `this` refer to a DOM element:

```
$('.thumb').hover(function() {
    // $(this) refer to $('.thumb')
});
```

or a object:

```
function foo(element) {
    this.a = 'a'; // Refer to object

    element.each(function() {
         $(this).css('color', 'red');

        // now this refer to current element of each, which is a DOM element
    })
}
```